# Time Limited Exceeded error C++ compile

Tags: c++, exception

I try to caculator power(n,p) and throw exception if n or p < 0 as following code.but I got an Time Limited Exceeded error when compile in [codechef](https://www.codechef.com/ide)
Question:
1. when Time Limited Exceeded error happen in C++?
2. which wrong with my code?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

class Calculator{
public:
    int power(int n,int p){
        if(n<0 || p < 0)
            throw "n and p should be non-negative";
        else
           return power(n,p);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Calculator myCalculator=Calculator();
    int T,n,p;
    cin>>T;
    while(T-->0){
        if(scanf("%d %d",&n,&p)==2){
            try{
                int ans=myCalculator.power(n,p);
                cout<<ans<<endl; 
            }
            catch(exception& e){
                cout<<e.what()<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever tried to run your code (even with simple inputs)? I suspect that you didn't.

Comment: The error is not C++ error, it is error from that web site. Read their help material to find out what it means, exactly (but most probably your program simply took too long to run, and they don't allow that, and to fix it you must make your program complete faster, or more likely to fix a bug in it).

Comment: yes, I tried following input   
2     
-3 5   
2 4

Comment: I don't know what sample input you tried to run. You should get infinite recursion with the simplest possible inputs. That's why I'm suspecting that you didn't try to run and debug before posting the question here.

Comment: And what happens when your test case is `2 4`?

Comment: Please at first give some effort.
Here in your power() method when you return then you need to call pow(n,p).

Comment: Hints for solving bugs like this in future: use a debugger, or lacking that, add debug prints. In this case, `Calculator::power` should print `n` and `p` on every call. That would have shown you the problem immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you have an infinite recursion in your code.

Look at this piece here:

```
int power(int n,int p){
    if(n<0 || p < 0)
        throw "n and p should be non-negative";
    else
       return power(n,p);
}
```

It will call `power(n, p)` infinite times, because you have no condition to quit execution. So you just put one function call after another on your stack. You do not even do any calculations!

You need a quit condition like this:

```
int power(int n,int p){
    if(n<0 || p < 0)
        throw "n and p should be non-negative";
    else if (p == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return n*power(n,p-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Calculator::power` is infinitely recursive: it calls itself with the same arguments it received. Surely there should be multiplication in there *somewhere*... ;-]

Comment: @Nidhoegger : I did give an idea: use different arguments than was received. SO is not a code-writing service, and the OP did not ask for the code to be fixed – they merely wanted to know what the problem is.

Comment: Of course it it not. I am with you there. But as you can see he is not that good in english and you could imply what he needs/wants. Like I said, you do not have to solve the problems for him, but give him a vague idea of how recursion is working...

Answer (score 0):

time limit exceeded is an error when no output was generated after a certain amount of time , in your case you have an infinite recursion you call power(a, b)
if a > 0 && b > 0 then you call power(a,b) so you enter in an infinite recursion 
try adding this

```
int power(int n, int p){ if(n<0 || p < 0) throw "n and p should be non-negative";
else if (p == 1) return 1;
else return n*(n,p-1);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct. Just a small case is not handled properly. While calculating the power of a number you have recursively called the same function with same parameters again. The base case has not been provided over here , thus your function doesnot know when to stop. You can do some changes like this :

use a base case in function : 
    if (p == 0) 
    return 1;

and recursively call your function with a deceremented power:
    return(n*(power(n,p-1)));

Your problem will be easily solved.